# AngularJS angular-ui-router not rendering view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to implement routing and have a Meteor app with Angular JS and my routing doesn't work... here is the index.html:

```
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="analytics">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the main.js file where I have all my configs stored:

```
  angular.module('emoti_analytics', [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  introStudentFlow.name,
  instructions.name, 
  'accounts.ui'
]).config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  console.log('got here!'); 
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'imports/components/studentFlow/introStudentFlow.html'
    }).state('studentInstructions', {
    url: '^/instructions',
    templateUrl: 'imports/components/instructions/instructionsFlow.html'
  });
}
```

Any idea of how to fix this? Right now it just renders an empty view and there are no errors in the JS console... please let me know what I'm doing wrong!(FYI the console.log does print out)

Here is the directory file structure (all the config stuff is under main.js)

[image: file directory]

Comment: it appears that you named your `ui-view` but used the state syntax that is for non-named views.  either remove `="a"` from the `ui-view` declaration or add a `views` object to your `state`. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#multiple--named-views

Comment: @Claies I changed the index.html to be what you said, and it still doesn't work. To give context: 

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="emoti_analytics">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

Comment: Not seeing`'ui.router'` in your module dependency list though that would throw an error about the `$stateProvider` missing. What's with your `templateUrl` values with the `../` prefix? You can't traverse above the document root

Comment: Check your network logs? Are you getting a 404 for the templateUrl?

Comment: @Phil added in the ui.router to module dependencies, still no go. The reason why I have ../ in the templateUrl is because my main.js file is stored under root/client, while all the views are stored under root/components. Would you recommend moving the main.js and index.html file out of the client? (also checked network logs and nothing else seems wrong)

Comment: The path to the `templateUrl` is relative to the URI set in your `<base>` tag. The templates are loaded by the browser like any other static resource

Comment: @Phil I uploaded my file structure above. The base tag is in index.html, which is one layer below where all the templates lie (under components/imports). Do you suggest moving index.html and main.js out of client? I'm unsure how to go about fixing this

Comment: What is your HTTP server document root set to?

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure what you mean by that. How do I set that/where do I set it/where do I know that?

Comment: Any 404'sin your browser's network tab?

Comment: What is the address in your browser that loads `index.html`? Is it `http://whatever/client`? If not, and you don't have any special server-side URL rewriting or proxying to allow you to access the `imports` folder via HTTP, you won't be able to load your templates (or anything else in `imports`)

Comment: @Phil I'm still confused what you mean. I don't have any special server-side URL rewriting/proxying, I'm simply using meteor to handle all the views. I'm just running localhost:3000 (which is the default URL) and what I think is rendering index.html.

Comment: @malix nope not that I see

Comment: Looking at some meteor tutorials, it appears you should just start your template paths with `templateUrl: 'imports/...'`.

Comment: @Phil added that change, still doesn't work...

Comment: Update your question with the current state of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111366/discussion-between-girlrockingguna-and-phil). @Phil also updated the code above